# How to place part on top of the terrain in Roblox?

Tags: roblox

I have a terrain generated in my ROBLOX game (hills, flats, rivers) and I have a model of a tree. Tree is just a group of "bricks" so it looks like kind-of a Minecraft tree.

Now I want to clone that tree programatically at run-time and I need to place that copy (clone) somewhere else on the map.

All of this is easy. But after I give my clone new coordinates (I keep coordinate for Y axis the same like my original tree), it's placed **or in the air, or it is under the surface** of my terrain.

How do I place it directly ON the terrain?
Or how do I get the Y-axis coordinate of that particular place on map?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

While answer from @Kylaaa is perfectly complete, here I include my solution, while I needed also an information about the material of the terrain in that place (rocks / grass / etc.)

```
function FindTerrainHeight(pos)

local VOXEL_SIZE = 4
local voxelPos = workspace.Terrain:WorldToCell(pos)

// my region will start at -100 under the desired position and end in +100 above desired position
local voxelRegion = Region3.new((voxelPos - Vector3.new(0,100,0)) * VOXEL_SIZE, (voxelPos + Vector3.new(1,100,1)) * VOXEL_SIZE)
local materialMap, occupancyMap = workspace.Terrain:ReadVoxels(voxelRegion, VOXEL_SIZE)

local steps = materialMap.Size.Y // this is actually 200 = height of the region

// now going from the very top of the region downwards and checking the terrain material
// (while it's AIR = no terrain found yet)
for i = steps, 1, -1 do

    if (materialMap[1][i][1] ~= Enum.Material.Air) then

        materialMap[1][i][1] ---> this is the material found on surface
        ((i-100) * VOXEL_SIZE) ---> this is the Y coordinate of the surface in world coordinates
    end
end

return false
end
```

**EDIT 2**

So it turns out that @Kylaaa's answer solves everything. It includes also terrain material! As 4th item in the tuple. It means my solution is too complicated with no reason. Use his solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try raycasting downward from your starting point until you find the terrain. [`game.Workspace:FindPartOnRayWithWhitelist()`](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Workspace/FindPartOnRayWithWhitelist) is great for this!

```
-- choose some starting point in world space
local xPos = 15
local yPos = 20
local zPos = 30

-- make a ray and point it downward.
-- NOTE - It's unusual, but you must specify a magnitude for the ray
local origin = Vector3.new(xPos, yPos, zPos)
local direction = Vector3.new(0, -100000, 0)
local ray = Ray.new(origin, direction)

-- search for the collision point with the terrain
local whitelist = { game.Workspace.Terrain }
local ignoreWater = true
local _, intersection, surfaceNormal, surfaceMaterial = game.Workspace:FindPartOnRayWithWhitelist(ray, whitelist, ignoreWater)

-- spawn a part at the intersection.
local p = Instance.new("Part")
p.Anchored = true
p.Size = Vector3.new(1, 1, 1)
p.Position = intersection -- <---- this Vector3 is the intersection point with the terrain
p.Parent = game.Workspace
```

If your model is moving around in unusual ways when you call `SetPrimaryPartCFrame()`, be aware that Roblox physics does not like interpenetrating objects. So models will often get pushed upwards until they are no longer interpenetrating. Objects that are `CanCollide = false` will not have this issue, but they will also fall through of the world if they are not `Anchored` or welded to a part is set to `CanCollide = true`.

Comment: Super, complete and clear answer. Thank you! 
I will post also my solution, while I needed also information about the type of the terrain in that place (rocks/grass/mud)

Comment: 'FindPartOnRayWithWhitelist()' also returns the material as the 4th item in the tuple. I didn't include it in my example because I thought it would clutter the answer.